# Как добавить возможность выбора варианта в консоли PHP

Tags: php

Есть ***консольный*** скрипт.
Хочу добавить возможность выбора файла из каталога.

**Максимально примитивно:**

Сканирую каталог и вывожу его содержимое:

```php
foreach (scandir('./Data') as $file){
 echo $file."\n";
}
```

А теперь как мне сделать чтобы пользователь мог по нажатию к примеру стрелок вверх или вниз выбрать нужный файл.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы выкините из головы фантазию про стрелочки, и решите делать нормальный консольный скрипт, то просто передавайте имя файла в скрипт в качестве параметра - так как это делают 100% консольных скриптов, написанных на РНР. Пользователи консольных скриптов обычно в состоянии найти нужный им файл самостоятельно.